# Developing a new file format for E-readers that supports special languages

Tags: file-format

Is it possible to develop a new file format that supports special languages like Persian? (and other right to left formats).

I've read following content:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-book

Comment: Why do you think Persian is special? And of course it is possible to develop a **new format**, you just slightly change one of the existing ones that support Persian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [epub3 standard](http://www.idpf.org/epub/30/spec/epub30-publications.html) offers a couple of new attributes specifically for RTL languages such as Persian and most free ePub3 apps, for example, [ADE 4](http://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/download.html), [Azardi](http://azardi.infogridpacific.com/), [Gitden Reader](http://gitden.com) and [iBooks](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/ibooks/id364709193?mt=8) display epub3 RTL books fine.

(There's an [Arabic test book](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B9g8D2Y-6aPLUUkxa2VYbURqVjA) at the official epub3 samples website that you can use for testing.)

BTW, if you happen to have a Kindle, you'll need to convert epubs to AZW3 files with Calibre, because the old MOBI format doesn't support RTL languages.

Answer (score 2):

Current formats e.g. ePub and Kindle already support this

They are basically a zip of HTML files. HTML includes pages in Persian etc.

Comment: The ePub standard certainly supports RTL languages, however, very few eInk readers do. The OP stands a much better chance with ePub3 apps (e.g. iBooks and Gitden Reader), because most ePub3 apps also support RTL languages.